# Why are there extra characters in my URL ID string?

Tags: reactjs, url, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to display the details of my "customers". However, I have a problem with my routes I think because in my URL I get
`http://localhost:3000/app/details-customer/%7Bid%7D` instead of the ID.

When I write `{path: BASEDIR + "/details-customer/{id}", component: Tabs2, type: "child"}`  in my routes and `<Link to = {"./details-customer/ {id}">`  in Customer.jsx I manage to display my Tabs2 page or when I write the ID in raw otherwise it does not work.

When for example, I write `<Link to = {"./details-customer/{id}" + customer.id}>` I get the URL with the correct ID but it returns me a blank page.

Someone can help me ?

Here my code in Customers.jsx:

```
      { switch (customer.etat) {
         case true:
                return (
                   <tr key={customer.id}>
                     <td>{customer.id}</td>
                     <td>{customer.lastName}</td>
                     <td>{customer.firstName}</td>
                     <td>{customer.email}</td>
                     <td>{customer.mobile}</td>
                     <td>{customer.company}</td>
                     <td>{customer.companyID}</td>
                     <td>
                      <Link to ={"./details-customer/{id}"} >
                        <button value={customer.id}>
                        </button>
                      </Link>
                      <button
                        onClick={() => showEditFormCustomer(customer.id)}
                        value={customer.id}
                        className="bi bi-pencil-fill">
                        </button>
                        <button
                        onClick={() => deleteCustomer(customer.id)}
                        value={customer.id}>
                      </button>
                   </td>
                   </tr>);
                   case false:
                  return "";
                   }})())}
```

Routes:

```
{
        path:BASEDIR+ "/customers", name: "Client", component: Customer ,icon: "people", type: "",
        child: [
           /* { path: BASEDIR+"/customers", name: "Clients"},
            { path: BASEDIR+"/add-customer", name: "Ajouter un client"},
            { path: BASEDIR+"/edit-customer", name: "Modifier un client"},*/
        ]
    },

    { path: BASEDIR+"/details-customer/{id}", component: Tabs2, type: "child"},
    //{ path: BASEDIR+"/add-customer", component: AddCustomer, type: "child"},
    { path: BASEDIR+"/customers", component: Customer, type: "child"},
```

Answer (score 4):

Placeholders should be defined with a `:`, so it will be `:id` instead of `{id}`:

```
{ path: BASEDIR+"/details-customer/:id", component: Tabs2, type: "child"},
```

Docs: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params

To debug your routes you can use the following setup:

```
{ path: "/a", component: AddCustomer, type: "child"},
{ path: "/b", component: Tabs2, type: "child"},
{ path: "/c/:id", component: Customer, type: "child"},
```

test links:

```
<Link to={"/a"}>Link A</Link>
<Link to={"/b"}>Link B</Link>
<Link to={"/c/20"}>Link C</Link>
```

Comment: To clarify, `%7B` and `%7D` are URL-encoded braces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already tried it does not work, I get a correct url ```http://localhost:3000/app/details-customer/20```, however it does not return me Tabs2

Comment: What is the value of BASEDIR? @Marine

Comment: The value of BASEDIR = ```/app```.

Comment: Could you try it without the BASEDIR? With a link of `<Link to={"/details-customer/20">test</Link>` ?

Comment: Check the following docs for an complete example: https://reactrouter.com/native/guides/quick-start

Comment: I just tried with what you told me, but it’s still not working.. I get ```http://localhost:3000/details-customer/20``` but no display my page Tabs2. I don’t see what is the problem.

Comment: does the /customers path work? Try making a simple test with /a, /b, /c to make sure your setup is correct

Comment: When I replace the link of the route and the link of <Link> with /a it works I get a display. So, I think my setup is correct

Comment: I Added an example setup, could you test that switching between /a and /b works?

Comment: The /a and /b links work, switching between/a and /b works too.
But the /c/:id still doesn’t work

Comment: Could you change the component of /b to be Tabs2? Check the updated example

Comment: I changed the component of /b, it works well it shows me Tabs2, but /c/:id does not work, it does not return me the Customer component.

Comment: Which component is shown? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Tabs2 and AddCustomer are displayed for the last test and Customer is not displayed.
I have no error but a warning: ```Warning: Can’t perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
in Customer (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (at Crm.jsx:79)```